# Python: How to use data that other classes produces?

Tags: python, class, object, pointers, kivy

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Foo:
def __init__(self):
    self.value_a = None
```

on a module and, on another module, I have another class:

```
class Bar:
def __init__(self):
    self.value_b = None

def value_update(self):
    self.value_b = some_operation
```

As python have no pointers, I cannot point an object's `self.value_a` on class Foo to the memory location of an `self.value_b` object on class Bar. So, in this case, what could I do? The point is that I would like, for example, that class Foo sees the values that class Bar produces and use them inside its own class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to change the variable defined in one class in the other class. In your current case, when you use the keyword `self`, you are referring to a particular instance of that class. The only way to change that particular value would be to create an instance of that class inside of the other class and change it there.

As an example, I would probably do something like

```
class Bar:
 def __init__(self):
    self.value_b = Foo()

 def value_update(self):
    self.value_b.a=new_value
```

Otherwise, I would probably get rid of `self` keyword and do this:

```
class Foo:
  value_a=None
  def __init__(self):
       paste some code here...
class Bar:
 def __init__(self):
    self.value_b = Foo.a # just copies the value, not reference!

 def value_update(self):
    self.value_b=new_value # this will NOT change Foo.a
    Foo.a=new_value #this will change it
```

P.S. In your case, I would say that the *second method* is more preferable

**Edit**: I think I was wrong, as it just copies the value from `Foo` rather than references it. Then, I suppose you might have to manually change `Foo.a` value every time you have to

Comment: yes Alex, you understood it well. Many thanks for taking your time helping me!